# In helm-find-files, how do you quit entering pattern and go back to selecting files?

Tags: helm, search

All I want is to just quit entering patterns and go back to searching a different directory. C-g quits the whole search process.

Comment: You should be able to simbly use `helm-find-files-up-one-level`, which is bound to `<left>`. This will remove the last search pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Answering myself after going through the source:

`helm-resume-previous-session-after-quit` (`C-x b`)

Comment: Please expand on your answer so that others who have the same problem will know how to fix it.